# Maximizing $\frac{ax}{cx+d}$ over $[0,1]$ using CVX

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, matlab, maxima-minima, cvx

I have the following concave function

$$f(x)=\frac{ax}{cx+d}$$

where $a, c, d > 0$ and $0 \le x \le 1$. How can I use CVX tools to maximize $f(x)$?

It seems that the CVX does not support such structure even if $f(x)$ is concave.

Comment: I have no idea about CVX or optimization, but maybe you could invert the function and then determine its minimum? Then $\min_{x}1/f(x)=\frac{c}{a}+\frac{d}{a}\frac{1}{x} $? So you actually only need to minimize $\frac{d}{a}\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: If $f$ concave, then $-f$ is convex. Can you solve $\min_x -f$?

Comment: I do know that $f$ is an increasing function. I just want to know how to max this kind of function using CVX.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I think the op just wants to learn cvx.

Comment: I think "math.stackexchange.com" is not the right site for questions not focusing on the mathematical background but specifically on Matlab programming. Maybe "stackoverflow.com" or "superuser.com" are matching better in this case.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & \dfrac{c x}{a x + b}\\ \text{subject to} & 0 \leq x \leq 1\end{array}$$

where $a, b, c > 0$ are given. Note that

$$\dfrac{c x}{a x + b} = \cdots = \frac ca - \frac{bc}{a} \left(\frac{1}{a x + b}\right)$$

Since $ \frac{bc}{a} > 0$, we have the following minimization problem

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \dfrac{1}{a x + b}\\ \text{subject to} & 0 \leq x \leq 1\end{array}$$

As $-\frac ba \notin [0,1]$, we have the following linear maximization problem

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & a x + b\\ \text{subject to} & 0 \leq x \leq 1\end{array}$$

and, thus, the maximum is attained at $x = 1$.

---

#### Code

Since I do not have CVX in this machine, I will use [CVXPY](http://www.cvxpy.org) instead. Let $a = b = 1$. Thus,

```
>>> from cvxpy import *
>>> x = Variable()
>>> objective = Minimize( inv_pos(x+1) )
>>> constraints = [ x >= 0, x <= 1 ]
>>> prob = Problem(objective,constraints)
>>> prob.solve()
0.4999999999223261
>>> x.value
1.0000000000418874
```

Note that the minimum is attained at $x = 1$.